# Pycharm Professional with WSL: Cannot read environment variables set with ~/.profile

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm writing a Django application that requires redisqueue, so I'm having to use WSL to continue development on Windows. I was pleased to find that Pycharm Professional allows you to configure a WSL Python interpreter. However, my first problem was that it was unable to find any Environmental Variables. No big deal, [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) says I can just `export` them from a file called `~/.profile`. I add them like so:

```
export SECRET_KEY="xxxxx"
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://xxxxx"
```

But my Pycharm interpreter can't find them, always complaining:

```
 SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

However, if I pull up an Ubuntu bash terminal and run Python3, it finds the value normally. I tried using `~/.pam_environment` and `./bashrc`, but neither of those worked, even when checked manually.

How can I give PyCharm/WSL access to my WSL Environ Vars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/22/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) which explains the official way to achieve what I wanted. Specifically, to User-Vars I added the key `WSLENV` with the value `SECRET_KEY/u:DATABASE_URL/u`. This fixed the problem immediately.